# What is the correct syntax for passing a static string with a select query?

Tags: php, sql, yii, static, yii2

This is my query within a Yii controller.  I am trying to pass the name of the controller as a static string. This syntax throws the error

> "Incorrect syntax near keyword LEFT."

If I use:

```
'Message' AS controllerName,
```

...then it works fine.

The full function:

```
/**
 * Datatable: Message
 *
 * @param $status
 */
public function actionMessage($status) {
    // only allow ajax requests to this action
    if (!Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest && !YII_DEBUG) {
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // start building the create command
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select("
            {Yii::app()->controller->id} AS controllerName,
            Message.MessageID AS primaryKey,
            Message.Name AS messageName,
            Message.Code AS messageCode,
            Message.CloneOf AS messageCloneOf,
            Message.IsActive AS messageIsActive,
            Message.IsArchived,
            Client.Name AS clientName,
            Workflow.WorkflowID AS workflowID,
            Workflow.Name AS workflowName,
            Workflow.Color AS workflowColor,

            STUFF((
                SELECT CAST(',' + aprv AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT MessageID, mv.RowInsertDate AS inDate, CONCAT(REPLACE(SUBSTRING ( a.Options ,0 , PATINDEX('%\",\"required\"%', a.Options )),'{\"name\":\"',' '), ' - All - ', CONCAT(u.FirstName,' ',u.LastName), ' on ' , mv.RowInsertDate) AS aprv
                            FROM MessageApproval mv
                            JOIN [User] u ON u.UserID = mv.UserID
                            JOIN [Action] a ON a.ActionID = mv.ActionID
                            WHERE mv.IsApproved=1
                        UNION
                        SELECT MessageID, mvl.RowInsertDate AS inDate, CONCAT(REPLACE(SUBSTRING ( a.Options ,0 , PATINDEX('%\",\"required\"%', a.Options )),'{\"name\":\"',' '), ' - ', l.Code, ' - ', CONCAT(u.FirstName,' ',u.LastName), ' on ' , mvl.RowInsertDate) AS aprv
                            FROM MessageApprovalLocale mvl
                            JOIN [User] u ON u.UserID = mvl.UserID
                            JOIN Locale l ON l.LocaleID = mvl.LocaleID
                            JOIN [Action] a ON a.ActionID = mvl.ActionID
                            WHERE mvl.IsApproved=1
                    ) AS approvalData
                WHERE (Message.MessageID = approvalData.MessageID)
                ORDER BY inDate DESC
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS Approvals,

            STUFF((SELECT CAST(',' + [Name] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
            FROM [Brand]
            JOIN MessageBrand ON Brand.BrandID = MessageBrand.BrandID
            WHERE (Message.MessageID = MessageBrand.MessageID)
            ORDER BY Brand.Name ASC
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS brands,

            STUFF((SELECT CAST(',' + [Name] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
            FROM [Communication]
            JOIN CommunicationRegionMessage ON Communication.CommunicationID = CommunicationRegionMessage.CommunicationID
            WHERE (Message.MessageID = CommunicationRegionMessage.MessageID)
            ORDER BY Communication.Name ASC
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS communications,

            STUFF((SELECT CAST(',' + [Name] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
            FROM [Track]
            JOIN TrackCommunication ON Track.TrackID = TrackCommunication.TrackID
            JOIN CommunicationRegionMessage ON TrackCommunication.CommunicationID = CommunicationRegionMessage.CommunicationID
            WHERE (Message.MessageID = CommunicationRegionMessage.MessageID)
            ORDER BY Track.Name ASC
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS tracks,

            STUFF((SELECT CAST(',' + [Name] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
            FROM [Series]
            JOIN SeriesTrack ON Series.SeriesID = SeriesTrack.SeriesID
            JOIN TrackCommunication ON SeriesTrack.TrackID = TrackCommunication.TrackID
            JOIN CommunicationRegionMessage ON TrackCommunication.CommunicationID = CommunicationRegionMessage.CommunicationID
            WHERE (Message.MessageID = CommunicationRegionMessage.MessageID)
            ORDER BY Series.Name ASC
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS series,

            STUFF((SELECT CAST(',' + [Name] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
            FROM [Campaign]
            JOIN CampaignSeries ON Campaign.CampaignID = CampaignSeries.CampaignID
            JOIN SeriesTrack ON CampaignSeries.SeriesID = SeriesTrack.SeriesID
            JOIN TrackCommunication ON SeriesTrack.TrackID = TrackCommunication.TrackID
            JOIN CommunicationRegionMessage ON TrackCommunication.CommunicationID = CommunicationRegionMessage.CommunicationID
            WHERE (Message.MessageID = CommunicationRegionMessage.MessageID)
            ORDER BY Campaign.Name ASC
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS campaigns,

            STUFF((SELECT CAST(',' + [Name] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
            FROM [Program]
            JOIN MessageProgram ON Program.ProgramID = MessageProgram.ProgramID
            WHERE (Message.MessageID = MessageProgram.MessageID)
            ORDER BY Program.Name ASC
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS programs,

            STUFF((SELECT '|' + Name + ';' + CAST(Template.RowUpdateDate AS VARCHAR)
            FROM [Template]
            JOIN MessageTemplate ON Template.TemplateID = MessageTemplate.TemplateID
            WHERE (Message.MessageID = MessageTemplate.MessageID)
            ORDER BY Template.Name ASC
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS templates,

            STUFF((SELECT CAST(',' + [Code] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
            FROM [Template]
            JOIN MessageTemplate ON Template.TemplateID = MessageTemplate.TemplateID
            WHERE (Message.MessageID = MessageTemplate.MessageID)
            ORDER BY Template.Name ASC
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS templateCodes,

            STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CAST([Name] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
            FROM [Connector]
            JOIN PublishMessage ON Connector.ConnectorID = PublishMessage.ConnectorID
            WHERE (Message.MessageID = PublishMessage.MessageID)
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS pubConnectors,

            PublishMessage.PublishStartDate AS pubStart,
            PublishMessage.PublishEndDate AS pubEnd,
            PublishMessage.PublishID AS pubID,

            STUFF((
                SELECT '|' + CAST(CONCAT(IsPublished,'.',Code,'.',SUBSTRING(PublishResponse, 0, 20)) AS VARCHAR)
                    FROM PublishMessage
                    JOIN (
                        SELECT MAX(Publish.PublishID) PublishID, MAX(PublishMessage.PublishMessageID) PublishMessageID, MAX(PublishMessage.MessageID) MessageID, Locale.Code, MAX(Publish.RowInsertDate) RowInsertDate
                        FROM Publish
                        JOIN Locale ON Locale.LocaleID=Publish.LocaleID
                        JOIN PublishMessage ON PublishMessage.PublishID = Publish.PublishID
                        WHERE MessageID=Message.MessageID
                        GROUP BY Locale.Code
                    ) AS latest ON latest.PublishMessageID=PublishMessage.PublishMessageID
                    ORDER BY IsPublished DESC, PublishMessage.RowInsertDate DESC
                FOR XML PATH ('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS pubStatus,

            PublishMessage.PublishResponse AS pubResponse,
            STUFF((SELECT '|' + MetaName + ':=' + MetaValue FROM ConnectorDetail WHERE ConnectorID = Connector.ConnectorID AND Show = 1 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as pubMeta
        ")
        ->from('Message')
        ->leftJoin('PublishMessage', 'PublishMessage.PublishMessageID = (SELECT MAX(PublishMessageID) FROM PublishMessage WHERE PublishMessage.MessageID = Message.MessageID AND PublishStartDate IS NOT NULL)')
        ->leftJoin('Connector', 'Connector.ConnectorID = PublishMessage.ConnectorID')
        ->join('Workflow', 'Message.WorkflowID = Workflow.WorkflowID')
        ->join('Client', 'Client.ClientID = Message.ClientID')
        ->where(DBHelper::whereFilterUserClient())
        ->order('Message.Name ASC');

    // apply status filter
    switch ($status) {
        case 'all':
            $command->andWhere('Message.IsArchived = 0');
            break;
        case 'archive':
            $command->andWhere('Message.IsArchived = 1');
            break;
        default:
            Yii::app()->end(sprintf('Invalid Status: %s', $status));
    }

    // get the query result
    $data = $command->queryAll();

    // Add in unapproved locales to the approvals (I couldn't find an efficient way to include this in main query)
    $localeApprovalMsgIDs = array_keys(MessageApprovalLocale::usesLocaleApproval());
    $unapprovedLocales = MessageApprovalLocale::unApprovedLocales($localeApprovalMsgIDs);

    foreach ($data as &$message) {

        if ( isset($unapprovedLocales[$message['primaryKey']]) ) {
            $message['Approvals'] = trim($message['Approvals'] . ',' . $unapprovedLocales[$message['primaryKey']]['Locales'],',');
        }
    }

    TableHelper::actionDataTable($data, $status == 'all' ? $this->dataTableColumns() : array_slice($this->dataTableColumns(), 2));
}
```

Comment: Please add the error thrown to the question. Please add the variant of SQL you are using to the question. Please add enough to your example problematic code that the opening parenthesis "(" is paired with a closing parenthesis ")". Based on the code snippet, I can't tell if your code looks like `...->select("... from table")` or like `...->select("...") from table`.

Comment: try var_dump the rowsql generated by your query  var_dump($command->sql)  so you take a look a the sql command effectively executed .

Comment: It doesn't complete the command so where would I place the var_dump statement?  This particular function has worked smoothly for quite some time.  I only added the one line to break it.

Comment: The command is executed  when  you call the $command->queryAll() ... but is build  by createCommand without execution  .. so you should obtain the sql code with command ..var_dump($command->sql)

Comment: Aha!  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use parameter binding for this:

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select("
        :controllerid AS controllerName,
```

...

```
->order('Message.Name ASC')
->bindParam(':controllerid', Yii::$app->controller->id);
```